# Ruby on Rails nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I somehow broke my application and can't seem to find my mistake and would appreciate some help a lot.

```
<%= debug @relquotes %>
 <%= debug @book%>
  <h4 class="text-center">Related Quotes</h4>
  <% @relquotes.each do |quote| %>
    <article class="blog-1 blog-archive py-5">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8 mr-md-auto ml-md-auto">
        <ol class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <h2 class="leading-normal mb-3"><%= quote.title %></h2>
            <div class="article-meta color-grey-50">
              <div class="media-body d-flex align-items-center">
                <p class="m-0 media-heading"><a>by </a><%= link_to quote.user.username, user_path(quote.user) %> &bull;
                  created <%= time_ago_in_words(quote.created_at) %> ago</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="quotebody"><%= sanitize quote.body.first(240) %> (...)</p>
            <a>  <%= link_to quote do %> Read more &rarr;</a>
              <% end %>
              </ol>
      </div>
    </article>
  <% end %>
```

Got this on my Book view and I have related quotes from books that I want to display with this

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :book
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy


  validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
  validates :body, presence: true, length: {minimum: 240}
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :category, optional: true
  has_many :quotes
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy

  has_attached_file :book_cover, styles: {book_index: '250x350>', book_show: '325x475>'}
  validates_attachment_content_type :book_cover, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

My books controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  layout "_app_nav"

  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /books/1
  def show
    @average_review = if @book.reviews.blank?
                        0
                      else
                        @book.reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
                      end
    @relquotes = @book.quotes

  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_book
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :description, :user_id, :book_cover, :category_id)
  end
end
```

The debug @book works fine and my book gets displayed. I confirmed via rails console that the quote is associated with the book.
The debug @relquotes resolves in plain '--- []'.
It was working before and I cant seem to find where I messed it up.

My `@relquotes` should display all the quotes that are associated with a book. I can confirm that quotes are associated with a book.

eg. quote has book_id = 1 - therefore the book with the book_id 1 should display this quote as a 'related quote'. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what's the full error?

Comment: my '@relquotes' should display my book related quotes. But instead it says that '@relquotes' is nil which clearly isn't the case

Comment: Which controller action are you referring to? Is it show? In any case, please remove the remaining actions to make your code more readable. The same goes for the view

Comment: Managed to solve this. Had to do with a stupid error. <li> <%= link_to '@'quote.book.title, '@'book %></li> was just referring me to the book show with book_id 1 while I was checking for different book_id's. <li> <%= link_to '@'quote.book.title, '@'quote.book %></li> did it. Didn't check the url because I thought it work because when I first tested it with book_id 1 it obviously worked... I feel stupid right now

Comment: It's okay, It happens :D